# xcode12.3 - building for iOS Simulator, but linking in object file built for iOS, file '...' for architecture arm64

Tags: ios, xcode, react-native

building for iOS Simulator, but linking in object file built for iOS, file '/Users/zzw/develop/xiaoming/code61/xiaozhikanfang/ios/Pods/GoogleMobileVision/BarcodeDetector/Frameworks/BarcodeDetector.framework/BarcodeDetector' for architecture arm64

-I tried a lot of solutions, not using Simulator, even running on iOS devices,Please help me on this regards Thanks

Comment: Try setting "Excluded Architectures" to `arm53` - [screenshot](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/aheze/DeveloperAssets/master/SetBuildSettings-arm64.png)

Comment: Thank, but that doesn't solve my problem